# Probability density Matrix Subtraction for heatmaps

Tags: r, heatmap, probability-density

Pretty new to R and stuck. I am attempting to normalize 2d probability density of a heat map by subtracting the 2d probability densities of another data set. I am looking where behaviors occur in space, however to do this I want to subtract out where the subjects just spend most of their time from were the behaviors are occuring to get an idea of relative density of just the behaviors. To do this I am trying to find the probability density matrices used to plot a heatmap for the following code:

```
ctrlplot<-ctrl %>% ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = stat(density)), contour = FALSE)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=matlab.like(15), na.value = "gray",
   as lowertick, uppertick, interval
   limit=c(0,1.3e-05))   #sets the static limit of probabilities.
```

This works to make the heat plot for either data set plot, however I cannot find where ggplot or stat_density_2d is storing the density data to subtract the two.

Alternatively I have tried to get just the densities for both data sets using the following code and storing it as the variable dens:

```
n<-100
h<-c(bandwidth.nrd(ctrl$x),bandwidth.nrd(ctrl$y))
dens<-kde2d(ctrl$x,ctrl$y,n=n,h=h)
```

Now I am not sure how to subtract the resulting z values and get it back into a heat plot. I know there is likely an easy solution for this, but I am  definitely stuck. Any advice on how to do this easier, or other suggestions on how to subtract the densities from one another would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
I found a way to pull the density data from ggplot. I was able to pull the density data from two different data sets, subtract the vectors and place the densities back into the original data frame using the following code:

```
ctrlplot<-ctrl %>% ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = stat(density)), contour = FALSE)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=matlab.like(15), na.value = "gray")


ctxplot<-ctx %>% ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = stat(density)), contour = FALSE)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=matlab.like(15), na.value = "gray")


ctrlplot2<-ggplot_build(ctrlplot)
gbctrl<-ctrlplot2$data[[1]]
 densctrl<-gbctrl$density

gbctx<-ggplot_build(ctxplot)
gbctx<-gbctx$data[[1]]
 densctx<-gbctx$density

diff_ctrl_ctx<-densctrl-densctx

gbctrl$density<-diff_ctrl_ctx
ctrlplot2$data[[1]]<-gbctrl

ctrlplot2
ctrlplot
```

However the last two plots ctrlplot (original) and ctrlplot2(subtracted densities) give the same plot. Not sure if I am not replacing the correct parts of the data frame so that it updates for the graphing part since there are different lists in the original ggplot_build.